# How to specify node_modules folder for locally referenced node module

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

> We need to specify node_modules folder for locally referenced node
>   module that resides in an external folder relative to the current
>   application folder.

We have a scenario where we are referencing an external common module’s js files within another client-side app, however the same node modules being references in both are being duplicated in the final build. we have tried using webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin() without any success.

The directory structure is as follows:

1. We have a private npm module on the local disk called ‘common’, and then we have our project folder called ‘app’.
2. Both folders are on the same level in directory structure & are under the same root.
3. The ‘app’ itself is a npm module & has a package.json file with its own node_modules folder.

   `|—root
    |— common/node_modules
    |— app/node_modules`

   We want to specify via configuration either via npm or web pack a way for the app to resolve references from its specified path of node_modules and not to refer to any other node_modules location including the one in common module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use npm link or just a simple symlink. Do something like that:

```
cd root/app (your app directory)
npm link ../common
```

OR

```
cd root/app (your app directory)
ln -s ../common node_modules/common
```

Comment: `npm link` is working but I have to specify `app/node_modules` folder in my `wepback.resolve.fallback` for it to work, doesn't seem right. Isn't there a better way of doing it?